# How to connect to a Kubernetes service via hostname instead of address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am currently deploying [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) on K8s (on EKS). I have managed to successfully deploy an Ingress Controller (used [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller)) and an ingress, and I can access the ingress through the internet. My objective is to be able to access the host and a path rather than the address.

In other words, right now to access the web-server I need to input an address like: `internal-k8s-airflow-deployment-aws-region.elb.amazonaws.com`. My goal is to access it using something like: `meow.myimaginarywebsite.com/airflow`.

### What I have tried to do

I am using [stable airflow Helm chart](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow) (not particularly looking for an answer referencing the chart), and I have modified the values for the web-server like:

```yaml
web:
    ## annotations for the web Ingress
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "alb"
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: "ip"

    labels: { }

    ## the path for the web Ingress
    path: "/airflow"

    ## the hostname for the web Ingress
    host: "meow.myimaginarywebsite.com"
    livenessPath: ""

    tls:
      enabled: false
```

Running `kubectl get ingress -n dp-airflow` I get:

```
NAME             CLASS    HOSTS                      ADDRESS                                                                               PORTS   AGE
airflow-web      <none>   meow.myimaginarywebsite.com   internal-k8s-airflow-deployment-aws-region.elb.amazonaws.com   80      141m
```

I have tried curling `meow.myimaginarywebsite.com` or `meow.myimaginarywebsite.com/airflow` but got: `Could not resolve host: meow.myimaginarywebsite.com/airflow`

For more context, It's worth mentioning that `meow.myimaginarywebsite.com` is a hosted zone. For example, running `aws route53 list-hosted-zones` I get (I also verified that these hosted zones are associated with the VPC I am deploying EKS on):

```
{
    "HostedZones": [
        {
            "Id": "/hostedzone/ABCEEIAMAREDACTEDIDEEE",
            "Name": "meow.myimaginarywebsite.com.",
            "CallerReference": "terraform-2012012012012",
            "Config": {
                "Comment": "Managed by Terraform",
                "PrivateZone": true
            },
            "ResourceRecordSetCount": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

It's worth mentioning that I am new to this task, so I would benefit the most from a conceptual understanding of what I need to do or guidance to be on the right track. To re-state my objective, I basically want to be able to put something like `meow.myimaginarywebsite.com/airflow` into the browser and then be able to connect to the webserver, rather than something like: `internal-k8s-airflow-deployment-aws-region.elb.amazonaws.com`. I am also happy to provide further details.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to add A or ALIAS record to Route 53 zone like that:

`meow.myimaginarywebsite.com` --> `internal-k8s-airflow-deployment-aws-region.elb.amazonaws.com`

After that at least you should be fine with DNS resolution.